# Parsin Json news-api Framework7

Tags: javascript, json, html-framework-7, jsonparser

I am tryong to parse news from the newsapi.org into a Jquery Mobile application but it seems not to work, as follows my js into the html code. Can someone give me a glue on what happens? it only displays the page with no responde back from the news api:

```
      <script>

      $.getJSON("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-sport&sortBy=top&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", function( data ) {

        console.log(data.articles)

        var arrayOfData = data.articles

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

          document.write(arrayOfData[i].title);
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write(arrayOfData[i].author);
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write(arrayOfData[i].description);
          document.write("<br><br>");

        }

      });

      </script>
```

Comment: does the console.log statement print something to the console?

Comment: Few question, have you import jquery? where's the script located? any console log result or error? I've tried in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfatje3a/) it works.

Comment: By the way, you should not expose your API key `apiKey=xxxxxxxx` on a public website...

Comment: It goes exactly in the middle of the page. That comes dynamically from an index.html page. When I click on the link it doesn't bring the Framework7 theme and style. The console prints out the news but the framework7 doesn't seem to wrap it into his style and instead doesn't bring results back.